# Ampersand in a Wordpress Page Title Causes Issues on Output

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace, html-entities, ampersand

I'm having a problem with ampersands in Wordpress Page Titles. I have a sidebar that displays the Page Parent Title & a list of children underneath. If the the Page Parent Title has an Ampersand it cuts off the title before the Ampersand and causes an issue with the list displayed below it. It also happens in a Breadcrumb as well. When I'm on the page with the ampersand title I have no issues but as soon as I go to a child of that page, that's when my issues start.

The title of the page is `ChildLinks-CCR&R`

Here is the code for my sidebar:

```
if ( !is_page('childcare-training')) {
$url = get_the_title($post->ID);

$output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc&exclude=802,1065,236,11&title_li=<h1 class="title1">'. $url .'</h1>' );
  if (is_page( )) {
    $page = $post->ID;
    if ($post->post_parent) {
      $page = $post->post_parent;
    }

    $titlenamer = get_the_title($page);
    $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=' );
    if ($children) {
      $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&depth=1&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=<h1 class="title3">' . $titlenamer . '</h1>');
    }
  }
echo $output;
}
```

**EDIT**

This seems to fix the problem for the sidebar:

```
$output = wp_list_pages (array(
            'echo' => 0,
            'child_of' => $page,
            'depth' => 1,
            'title_li' => '<h1 class="title3">' . $titlenamer . '</h1>'
        ));
```

I have tried `str_replace` in the code above like this:

```
$titlenamer = get_the_title($page);
$titlenamer = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $titlenamer);
$titlenamer = str_replace("&amp;amp;", "&amp;", $titlenamer);
```

I have also tried using `html_entity_decode` multiple ways:

```
$titlenamer = html_entity_decode(get_the_title($page), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$titlenamer = html_entity_decode(get_the_title($page));
$titlenamer =get_the_title(get_the_title($page));
```

I've also tried to add `&amp;` into the title while editing the wordpress page and `&#38;`

Any Ideas to solving this? Besides renaming the page with `and` instead of `&`..
I've also posted in [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/ampersand-in-title-causes-issues-in-breadcrumbs-sidebar)

Comment: So what I've figured out so far.. is if I use `wp_list_pages (array(
    'echo' => 0,
    'child_of' => $page,
    'depth' => 1,
    'title_li' => '<h1 class="title3">' . $titlenamer . '</h1>'
   ));` Seems to be working for the sidebar.. Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Try using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the values you are inserting into the querystring.